# PHP and SQLite Connection Issue

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to insert into an SQLite database file using PHP. I have an existing database file that I can verify is working with SQLite Database Browser.  This is the error I get:

```
Warning: sqlite_query() [function.sqlite-query]: no such table: players in 
C:\wamp\www\espnapi\getPlayers.php on line 17

if ($db = sqlite_open("nhl.db", 0666, $sqliteerror)) { 

    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO players (url, team, number, firstname, 
        lastname, position)
        VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", $aTempPlyr[0],   
        $aTempPlyr[1], $aTempPlyr[2], $aTempPlyr[3], $aTempPlyr[4], $aTempPlyr[5]); 

    sqlite_query($db, $sql);
}
```

Comment: It clearly says "no such table: players". What is the schema of the Database? Is the table created??

Comment: Yes, on SQLite Database Browser it shows a table players

Comment: Try adding a full path string to the database name in your  `sqlite_open` call such as "/path/to/nhl.db"

Comment: @PositiveLogic: same result

Comment: I gave up and just exported the data to a csv file and then imported it with SQLite Database Browser